# docker-compose failed to build: COPY failed: no such file or directory при создании образа на базе nginx

Tags: nginx, docker, docker-compose

Проблема в следующем:
решил собрать проекты с помощью docker-compose и столкнулся с такой ситуацией: по отдельности образы собираются, но при сборке второго образа выдается ошибка: `failed to build: COPY failed: no such file or directory`
вот как выглядит yml файл:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  ep.seabattleai.web:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}epseabattleaiweb
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: EP.SeaBattleAI.Web/Dockerfile
    ports:
    - 8888:80

  seabattleai-frontend:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}seabattleai
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: seabattleai-game-client/Dockerfile
    ports:
    - 9999:80
```

вот как выглядит проблемный Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx:alpine

EXPOSE 80

WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html

COPY ./dist/seabattle-game-client/ .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Доброго времени суток.

Полагаю проблема в том, что в композ-файле опция `dockerfile` указывает на вложенную директорию, а `context` на корневую. Поэтому Dockerfile из вложенной пытается выполнить копирование из корневой, где скорее-всего нет директории `dist`.

Для того, чтобы Dockerfile "искал" `dist` во вложенной папке, можно скорректировать Ваш композ-файл следующим образом:

```
build:
  context: ./EP.SeaBattleAI.Web
  dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

З.Ы. Я бы не рекомендовал использовать композ версии 3, если не планируете запускать свой проект в режиме [swarm](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/).

Comment: да. проблема была в этом. Только другой проект надо было так изменить   
  build:
      context: ./seabattleai-game-client
      dockerfile: Dockerfile